# How do i generate an hmac with sha-512?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hmac, sha512

So, i'm writing a python program, actually my first "big" one, that, at a certain point, needs to generate an hmac with sha-512, from a message and a key.

Let's say i have:

```
key = 'ff'
seed = '238973:a665f3e641d9a402df3f9d5d9a236cb8061a2437ee47de8b3c8091774484b8b3:238973'
bkey = key.encode()
bseed = seed.encode()
string = hmac.new(bKey, bSeed, 'sha3_512')
digest = string.hexdigest()
print(str(digest))
```

```
>>>92b6c5ccc654c21838cb72e932de0feaf898398300e9755b2c91553c9db0bea99a5139055b5471142b299361c6ece4b51f2f26777a6f18f0db27775625e6948f
```

However when i go to https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output it gives me another result:

```
249667dabafbd3fa123b9749c6b23bc90c935e30e1372f26bbab2defa791fc915d60d406efe1b165befd4a1b6dc34fcf2f0975db08a7a2938964e99ea0419dcf
```

which i know for a fact to be the correct one, can somebody explain me why that is? I've been looking online for hours but it seems like i'm running in circles or i don't fully grasp how the hmac works.
I would greatly appreciate your help, it's the only bit i'm missing to finish this program.

Comment: It's probably that you're running sha3 512 and the website you linked to is, I assume sha2 512.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sha3_512` is not the same implementation as `sha512` - the first is based on [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3), while the second is based on [the older SHA-2 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2). Use `sha512` instead when creating your hmac to use the SHA-2 version:

```
>>> hmac.new(b'ff', b'238973:a665f3e641d9a402df3f9d5d9a236cb8061a2437ee47de8b3c8091774484b8b3:238973', hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
'249667dabafbd3fa123b9749c6b23bc90c935e30e1372f26bbab2defa791fc915d60d406efe1b165befd4a1b6dc34fcf2f0975db08a7a2938964e99ea0419dcf'
```